# How to resize an image when pixel dimensions are locked?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I resize my image so the height is 180 and the width is 120?  Currently when I try to change the size, I'm forced to keep the dimensions fixed.  I see that the lock is enabled but I don't know how to remove it.  The file is a png.  I've tried saving in Adobe's PSD format but that didn't make a difference.

[image: Image Size]

Comment: Don't confuse "dimensions" with "ratio of dimensions" (aka "proportions"). The "Constrain Proportions" check box forces any change to a measurement to recalculate the other dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By unchecking the "Constrain Proportions" the lock on the dimensions is removed, and you can set the horizontal and vertical size independently.

Resizing the image without the lock may stretch it in either dimension, which might not be desirable. But if the aspect ratio stays close to original, it's probably not a problem.

Comment: + If you want to keep the contents of the image intact and resize the image area (=canvas), choose `Canvas size…` from the `Image` menu. That will pad/cut your canvas to your desired size and keep the original in its original size.